# How to convert Euclidean distance to range 0 and 1 like Cosine Similarity?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, text-mining, bigdata

Want to map Euclidean distance to the range [0, 1], somewhat like the cosine similarity of vectors.

For instance

```
input  output
  0      1.0
  1      0.9  approximate
  2      0.8 to 0.9 somewhere
 inf     0.0
```

I tried the formula `1/(1+d)`, but that falls away from 1.0 too quickly.

Comment: Your English is good enough for this.  However, your mathematical details are lacking.  "Like" cosine similarity doesn't tell us what you need.  All we know is that you want to map something into the range [0,1].  Why does 1 map to 0.9, specifically?  How is 1/(1+d) not correct?

Comment: d1 and d2 have distance = 1, that mean, d1 and d2 similar, corresponding 0,9 or some other number in cosine similarity.

Comment: if distance d1 and d2 = 2 => 1/1+d = 0,3. I expect that value equal 0,8 or 0,9, because d1 and d2 are close together.

Comment: We need you to give details on what sort of mapping you want.  You need to describe your idea of "close" in clearer terms.  All you've given us is the endpoints and a vague idea of two other data points.

Comment: @Prune Thanks you so much for editing my question, that's exactly my mean

Comment: Great!  Now, do the answers below help?

Comment: I have just found a solution, first, i normalized two vectors follow this tutorial: http://www.fundza.com/vectors/normalize/. Second, i caculate Euclidean distance with normalized vetor. Third, i apply formula 1/1+d. And the result seem correct

Comment: Excellent!  When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you want the fraction's denominator to grow more slowly (the denominator is the bottom part, which you have as (d+1) so far).  There are various ways to handle this.  For instance, try a lower power for **d**, such as

```
1 / (1 + d**(0.25))
```

... or an exponential decay in the denominator, such as

```
1 / (1.1 ** d)
```

... or using a trig function to temper your mapping, such as

```
1 - tanh(d)
```

Would something in one of these families work for you?

Comment: Where can I know more about all those equations? Currently building something with TS-SS similarity and the result is above 1, can be 2 to infinity I guess. So I'm guessing the TS-SS result is distance then? I'm not sure. And the most fit converter is using 1 / (1.1 ** d). The other ones resulting like lower similarity result, like to low, something (should be 0.9, but instead 0.5)
Can other algorithm like TS-SS use those equations to convert distance to similarity as well?

Comment: "all those equations" are simply the algebra I learned before college.  Look for trig functions, exponential functions, polynomials.  Pick some reasonable values for the function you want; draw it on graph paper.  Compare that to the functions you looked up, and see what has a comparable shape.  Then configure that class of function to get the specific values you want.

You posted a new question as a comment.  If you "do the right thing" and post a new question, then please tag me in a comment, and I'll likely find it in a day or two.  I can help then.

Comment: i tried to tag you in the comment of my question, but can't find how. Just want to be quick, here is my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74780779/19323874). Thanks