# How to convert TS-SS result to similarity measure between 0 - 1?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, similarity, cosine-similarity, euclidean-distance

I'm currently developing a question plugin for some LMS that auto grade the answer based on the similarity between the answer and answer key with cosine similarity. But lately, I found that there is a better algorithm that promised to be more accurate called [TS-SS](https://github.com/taki0112/Vector_Similarity/blob/master/TS-SS_paper.pdf). But, the result of the calculation 0 - infinity. Being not a machine learning guy, I was assuming that the result maybe a distance, just like Euclidean Distance, but I'm not sure. It can be a geometry or something, because the algorithm is calculating the triangle and sector, so I'm assuming that it is a geometric similarity or something, I'm not sure though.

So I have some example in my note, and then I tried to convert it with what people suggest, `S = 1 / (1 + D)`, but the result was not what I'm looking for. With cosine similarity I got 0.77, but with TS-SS plus equation before, I got 0.4. And then I found this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43689075/19323874) answer that uses `S = 1 / (1.1 ** D)`. When I tried the equation, sure enough it gave me "relevant" result, 0.81. That is not far from cosine similarity, and in my opinion the result is better suited for auto grading than 0.77 one based on the answer key.

But unfortunately, I don't know where that equation come from, and I tried to google it but no luck, so that is why I'm asking this question.
How to convert the TS-SS result to similarity measure the right way? Is the `S = 1 / (1.1 ** D)` enough or...?

Edit:

When calculating TS-SS, it is actually using cosine similarity calculation as well. So, if the cosine similarity is 1, then the TS-SS will be 0. But, if the cosine similarity is 0, the TS-SS is not infinty. So, I think it is reasonable to compare the result between the two to know what conversion formula will be used

```
TS-SS  Cosine Similarity
38.19   0
7.065   0.45
3.001   0.66
1.455   0.77
0.857   0.81
0.006   0.80
0       1

another random comparison from multiple answer key
36.89   0
9.818   0.42
7.581   0.45
3.910   0.63
2.278   0.77
2.935   0.75
1.329   0.81
0.494   0.84
0.053   0.75
0.011   0.80
0.003   0.98
0           1

comparison from the same answer key
38.11   0.71
4.293   0.33
1.448   0
1.203   0.17
0.527   0.62
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: That result didn't "come from" somewhere you can simply research.  As I said in the comments of that other quest, it comes from being familiar with algebra, and fitting an equation to the characteristics needed.  I managed to give that OP (original poster) an equation to fit, because they gave clear characteristics of the desired equation.

Comment: If you want comparable help, then you need to specify what you want, with qualitative properties for us to know the general shape of the function, and enough quantitative properties to provide useful coefficients for the class of equation.  "Relevant", "not far", and "better suited" are okay for general discussion, but we need a clearer description of what you *do* want, rather than only vague comparisons.

Comment: @prune basically,  what I want is to convert the TS-SS result to similarity measure between 0 - 1, and I don't know what formula that suited most for my particular problem, which is comparing two documents, answer key and answer response. Is that clear enough? `qualitative properties for us to know the general shape of the function, and enough quantitative properties to provide useful coefficients for the class of equation`

I'm sorry, I don't understand this part. Can you simplify it more? Thanks

Comment: A typical similarity will map D=0 to S=1, and D=infinity to S=0.  However, to craft you a function, we need some ideas of the values in between.  If the distance is 1 instead of 0, about how far should the similarity fall away from 1?  How about 10, 100, ... ?  What does that curve look like?  How fast and how far does it drop from 1 toward 0?

Comment: Qualitative properties are a general description of shape: the qualities of the curve.  For instance, "the function has to be concave up/right, with a smooth slope."  Quantitative properties are those you can measure.  For instance, "In general, increasing the distance by 10x should cut the similarity roughly in half."

Comment: @Prune I have edited my question. Is that the curve you were talking about?

Comment: Yes, that's it.  Please check your data: there's a distinct blip at (0.006, 0.80).  I would expect that value to be about 0.99, rather than regressing to 0.80

Comment: @Prune nope, it's all correct data. The results of the calculations are obtained from documents in different contexts. For example data number 1 - 3 is a comparison with answer key and student response about difference between P2P and client server, and 4 - end is about usability testing. So different length of document may result in different result. I was going to give you a data from same answer key, but the result was back and forth. 39.11 of TS-SS will result 0.71 in cossim, but 0.527 TS-SS will result in 0.62 in cossim. I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

With these new figures, the answer is simply that we can't give you an answer.  The two functions give you a distance measure based on metrics that appear to be different enough that we can't simply transform between TS-SS and CS.  In fact, if the two functions are continuous (which they're supposed to be for comfortable use), then the transformation between them isn't a bijection (two-way function).

For a smooth translation between the two, we need at least for the functions to be continuous and differentiable for the entire interval of application. a small change in the document results in a small change in the metric.  We also need them to be monotonic over the interval, such that a rise in TS-SS would *always* result in a drop in CS.

Your data tables show that we can't even craft such transformation functions for a single document, let alone the metrics in general.

---

The cited question was a much simpler problem: there, the OP already has a transformation with all of desired properties; they needed only to alter the slopes of change and ensure the boundary properties.